# Currently angular 5 is giving me different problems in firefox and chrome

Tags: angular, angular5

I've been trying to resolve since few days but still I'm getting errors. Updated angular cli, nodejs to latest but still getting following errors. And again I'm confused with errors that is different in firefox and chrome. Please help me I have just started angular to learn for my job. I'm still confused whether there is an error in my code or the browsers are confused like me.

**In Chrome**

```
  'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserName' of undefined
```

**In firefox**

```
  TypeError: _co.user is undefined
```

**Code snippets**

```
  <input type="text" name="UserName" #UserName ="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.UserName">
```

**sign-up-components.ts**

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { User } from '../shared/user.model';
  import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
  import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';

  @Component({
       selector: 'app-sign-up',
       templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css']
  })
  export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  user : User;

  constructor( private userService : UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
  }

  OnSubmit(form : NgForm){

      this.userService.addUser(form.value).subscribe((data : any)=> {

            if(data.Succeeded ==true){
            console.log("transferred successfull");
        }
     });
    }   

  }
```

**user.model**

```
   export class User {

     UserName: string;
     Password: string;
     Email: string;
     FirstName: string;
     LastName: string;

  }
```

Please if anyone has gone through this then update me with the solutions.
since i have started the angular I have updated cli twice i guess. At the beginning there was no such error. But since I have updated the error is coming.

Comment: You never actually set `user` therefore it will be undefined. You need to set it somewhere or treat undefined/null accordingly.

Comment: Yes  you were right Alex... Thanks for pointing out...

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can solve the issue :

You can solve this with `safe operator` and removing `2 way binding`

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" #UserName ="ngModel" [ngModel]="user?.UserName">
```

**OR**

Component Side:

```
user : User = new User(); // this should initialise the user varible here
```

Comment: @JohnStevenson , will you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR TypeError: "_co.user is undefined"

Usually you get this error when the variable declared in `.ts` file is different from the variable which is used in `.html file ngModel`

so check whether the names are same or not.

For example in `.ts` file you declared a variable user : any
and in .html file if you are using like `[(ngModel)] ="users.name"`
then you face this error. so check the variable names :)